# How to get the Id of a particular control in UserControl in JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a UserControl in asp.net page. The UserControl contains RadioButtonList control having 4 items. For each control in RadioButtonList, I have unique ID with it as follows.

```
rdlUser_0 - Leave
rdlUser_1 - Available
rdlUser_2 - Available at Home
rdlUser_3 - Available at Office
```

The following is the Markup for RadioButtonList

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlUser" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

How can I attach change event to rdlUser in jQuery?

[image: ConfirmationMessage]

Comment: Unique ID but common name :)

Comment: Give them a common class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("[id^='rdlUser_'][type='radio']").change(function(){ //your code here });
```

This will bind a function to change event of all radio buttons

Comment: But with this code, it is firing 4 times i.e., for each item in RadioButtonList. How can I fire change event when the user tries to change from one item to other item in the given rdlUser list?

Comment: It is firing only once in my case. Event will be raised for the selected radio button. Also you have set AutoPostBack to true, this will also not allow the client side jquery change events to run

Comment: Actually it is firing 4 times. The message box is overlapped one after the other.  Changed my question to attach the overlapping picture.

Comment: That pop up is show because you have set AutoPostBack property for radio button list to true

Comment: Even after removing AutoPostBack, it is functioning the same way

Comment: This is the code I have placed inside the change function `if (arg == true) {
                $find('<%= FindControl("txtUser").ClientID %>').set_value("");
                $find('<%= FindControl("txtUser").ClientID %>').disable();
            }    
            else {
                $this.siblings('input').prop('checked',true);
                var rdlUser = document.getElementById(radioBtnId);
                rdlUser.checked = false;
                $this.prop('checked', false);
            }`

Comment: this line `$this.siblings('input').prop('checked',true);` doesn't make sense. They are radios so won't that check them all? Is it possible that this is firing the other events?

Comment: @cpk_2011 I didn't find anything inside change function's code. But there is some other code that is causing you to move away to another page